# Обращение к элементу вложенного массива

Tags: html, массивы

Есть массив

```
var optionsData = {
  information_system: ['', 'СЭД', 'Антивирус'],
  services_emts: ['', 'Active Directory', 'Почтовые сервисы'],

  'СЭД': ['','Управление правами доступа', 'Техническая поддержка'],
  Антивирус: ['', 'Контроль функционирования'],
  'Active Directory': ['', 'Управление доступом', 'Техническая поддержка'],
  'Почтовые сервисы': ['', 'mail.ru', 'yandex.ru']
};
```

Как правильно обратиться к элементу массива, например Техническая поддержка массива СЭД в поле id?

```
<form action="[% Env("CGIHandle") %]" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id='Active Directory(3)'>
```

Comment: optionsData['СЭД'][2]

Comment: не выходит, action не срабатывает. Если напишу id="Техническая поддержка" работает, но мне надо как-то отличать элементы массива

Comment: для формирования html-контента "налету" из произвольных данных (определенных тут же, на странице, как js-массив), во время рендеринга контента броузером, можно использовать js-шаблонизаторы (_handlebars_, _twig_, _..._) или делать это самостоятельно, с помощью манипуляций с DOM на javascript  (_document.createElement_).

Answer (score 0):

После того как вы получаете данные с массива вам нужно его записать в id примеру

```js
var optionsData = {
  information_system: ['', 'СЭД', 'Антивирус'],
  services_emts: ['', 'Active Directory', 'Почтовые сервисы'],

  'СЭД': ['','Управление правами доступа', 'Техническая поддержка'],
  Антивирус: ['', 'Контроль функционирования'],
  'Active Directory': ['', 'Управление доступом', 'Техническая поддержка'],
  'Почтовые сервисы': ['', 'mail.ru', 'yandex.ru']
};
$('.test').attr('id', optionsData['Active Directory'][1]);

$('.test').text(optionsData['Active Directory'][1]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">

</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, но мне было бы удобнее присваивать id элементам в самом массиве. реально ли это?
код в html а не в php

Comment: Данный масивы вы получаете в html коде или же в самом Php ?

Comment: в html. два массива выпадающим списком, один зависит от другого. применял javascript.
Нужно, чтобы по выбору элемента из второго списка происходило действие.

Comment: Тут я думаю не обойтись без php ajax запрос отправить так удобнее будет

Answer (score 0):

```
function showNames(v, id) {
  var mas = optionsData[v] || [];
  var el = document.getElementById(id);

  el.innerHTML = '';
  el.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));

  for(var i = 0; i < mas.length; i++) {
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.innerHTML = mas[i];
    opt.value = mas[i];
    el.appendChild(opt);
  }
}
```